# jsf2 don't work ,url pattern

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I created application with JSF2 Spring and Hibernate, but when I run it I obtain this error :

```
Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: clock javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of your exception, as well as *properly indented* relevant code that reproduces your problem. Also, pay some respect to the community and format your question properly. As to the solution, check one of the two following points, one of which is the cause of your problem: (1) remove conflicting PrimeFaces jars from your classpath and (2) check out PrimeFaces version, as `<p:clock>` tag was introduced in version 3.5.

Comment: **thank you but the problem is when i put my url pattern *.jsf the home page is empty **

Comment: You seriously think that we can help you with 3 lines of informations? We are unfortunatly not in front of your computer, we need details!

Comment: Sorry , i mean that when i run application my home page is empty,i think that i have a problem with jsf2 because when i put my url pattern *.jsf the home page is empty but when i put *.xhtml it work but a lot of exeption are generated

Comment: please i need help , i can't answer my question after 8hour ,i can only comment

Answer (score 0):

Take a look inside your web.xml and make sure you have :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also that your view files are ending with `.xhtml`

Now you can change your default extension :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Finally, make sure you changed your welcome file :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user2338085 you still get the blank home page again?

Comment: If you don't get any errors in log I still can't help much. By curiosity, is there any JSF code inside the rendered blank page if you check the source?